# Radiobox checked set value in db

Tags: php, html, mysql

In database this row is set as tinyint and it have default value as 1 and on my form I have 2 radiobox options.. how can I make if I check "Yes" value in db to be added as 2 and when I check "No" value in db to be added as 1

HTML CODE:

```
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1"> Yes
 </label>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2" checked="checked"> No
 </label>
```

PHP code:

```
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=;dbname=', '', '');

$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO games (name, url, yt_id, steam_id, source) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$statement->execute(array($_POST['gtitle'], $_POST['keysl'], $_POST['video_id'], $_POST['appid'], $_POST['slink']));
```

ohh and that row in database is called "exclusive"
And the form where are included those 2 radiobox when I press submit button it's imported in db.

Comment: for one thing, you have 5x columns, 6x placeholders and only 5 POST arrays. Typo? You also have no matching inputs for the POST arrays (probably irrelevant), unless this is a "show me how" type of question.

Comment: Simply set your `value` attributes as so? I.E. `<input type="radio" ... value="1">` etc..

Comment: Yep, it's a "show me how". I've no idea why you haven't tried anything, so how do you expect to learn from probable mistakes? You obviously have other inputs where you're using those present POST arrays for; so why the question? Did you try something and it failed? If so, show us and we'll be happy to help and to show you what you may have done something wrong.  What you have now is done by simply changing the values, *"n'est-ce pas?"*

Comment: No need to edit your original question by overwriting it with **SOLVED**. Accepting an answer does that for you. George's comment up there would have solved this within mere minutes of your posting but didn't bother trying anything.

Comment: You went and edited again after I performed a rollback to the original post. The question has been flagged for moderation and stands at being locked where it will not be editable, even by yourself.

Comment: @greg-449 You went and re-edited the question when there's a moderation flag pending for this question. I'm hoping there won't be any bearing on this. If so, then your edit would have probably made my flag declined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add the values you want to your HTML

```
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="2"> Yes
 </label>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="1" checked="checked"> No
 </label>
```

Then add it to your query

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO games (name, url, yt_id, steam_id, source, exclusive) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$statement->execute(array($_POST['gtitle'], $_POST['keysl'], $_POST['video_id'], $_POST['appid'], $_POST['slink']),$_POST['inlineRadioOptions']))
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked!